# adding static method to class in c#, I know you can't want alternatives

Tags: c#, dsl

I'm trying to work Domain Specific Language constructs into my api.  What I would really love to do is be able to add a static method to a class via extension, but i have researched that this is not possible from this site. So let's talk about what i really want to do by example.

Say you have some class that serves as a data service (could be a database, or rest or whatever).

The class requires you to initialize it with some, let's say, location data so that it knows where to point.  This location information is not going to be known till runtime.

Normally you would do . . .

```
DataService service = new DataService( locationData );
Order = service.getOrderDetails( orderId );
```

However, in almost all cases, the user will just need to ask on question of the DataService and then move on, close scope.  I would like some idiom that makes this friendlier to the user.  When I learned of extension methods by wish was to do this . . .

```
Order = DataService.at(location).getOrderDetails(orderId);
```

This, of course, is also possible, but I would like to put this pattern/idiom on to many classes that have this notion of a location.  I have tried extension methods (cant be static).  I have tried inheriting from a GenericClass that provides an at method:

```
public class DSL<T> 
  where T : new()
{
  public T at( Location location )
  {
     return new T(location);
  }
}
```

you can not pass args to a constructor for a variable type :(

I dislike doing the following:

```
public class DSL<T> 
  where T : ILocationable, new()
{
  public T at( Location location )
  {
     T result = new T();
     result.setLocation( location );
     return result;
  }
}
```

because i do not like classes that can be instantiated and not initialized.

What alternatives do you guys have out there, either to add this "at" method or to provide a better idiom for handling this type of api.

UPDATE:

I came up with a mechanism that does what I need:

First I have this in a file in my library/tools area.  The file is called DSL.cs
contents below:

```
namespace R3
{
    static public class DSL
    {
        static public Services.CloudConnection Cloud( string cloud )
        {
            return Services.CloudFactory.get(cloud);
        }
    }
}
```

When I declare a method I want to use this with technique

```
    static public void fixSequenceError(this CloudConnection cloud, OrderId id )
    {            
        if( inSequenceError(cloud, id ) )
        {
            cloud.db.setOrderStatus(id, BLAH);
            cloud.db.setOrderItemsStatus(id, BLAHBLAH);
        }
    }
```

then in any file i want to use this idiom in I need to do something funky instead of a standard include:

```
using static R3.DSL;
```

Now I can type stuff like:

```
Cloud( locationData ).fixSequenceError
```

or

```
Cloud(orderInfo.cloudLocation).db.changeAppOrderStatus
```

For efficiency, the CloudFactory is returning a statically allocated object that is associated with that cloudLocation, think many different singletons hashed to identifier.  When `Cloud( location ).foobar(orderId)` is invoked I'm calling foobar using the object specific to that location.  I'm doing so without having to prepend every action with `Cloud cloud = CloudFactory.getCloud(location)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use reflection like this:

```
public static class DSL
{
    public static T at<T>(Location location)
    {
        return (T)typeof(T).GetConstructor(new[]{typeof(Location)})?.Invoke(new object[] {location});
    }
}
```

This method tries to get a `ConstructorInfo` and invokes it with the provided `Location` argument.

---

When the type `T` does not have a constructor taking only a `Location` argument, `at` will return `null`.

---

**UPDATE:** Decided to make the class static, so you don't need to create an instance when you just want to call it like this:

```
Order order = DSL.at<DataService>(location).getOrderDetails(orderId);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your method would have to be changed to a static, I think generic instance methods require the class definition to allow be typed.

Comment: @ErikPhilips No they don't. Just tried it. You can use this class like `DSL dsl = new DSL(); Order order = dsl.at<DataService>(location).getOrderDetails(orderId);` Works perfectly.

Comment: Oh wait you're right, I was thinking of constructors.

Answer (score 0):

You could adopt a builder pattern perhaps to avoid classes which are constructed but not valid (although the builder itself might fall into this category):

```
Order order = new OrderBuilder().using(dataService).at(location).getOrderById(id).Build();
```

This gives the sort of fluent api you're looking for. I have recently used this for a project.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like some idiom that makes this friendlier to the user.

In your case it appears you don't want to use the Object Oriented Programming the way it was designed in c# but would rather use any a Fluent that allows for *friendlier code for another programmer* (not user).

In this case it seems your only solution would be to use the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).  It's typically used to validate parameters as they are passed in, but in this case can be used to encapsulate the creation of a class to prevent uninitialized classes.

(I'll also mention that [lowercased methods are against Microsoft guidelines for naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx), so I'll be using Pascal casing in my code.)

```
DataService.at(location).getOrderDetails(orderId);
```

Could be coded like:

```
public class DataService
{
  private DataService(Location location)
  {
    //
  }

  public static DataService At(Location location)
  {
    var result = new DataService(location);
    return result;
  }

  public Order GetOrderDetails(int orderId)
  {
  }
}
```

Then the code would look exactly like your example:

```
DataService.At(myLocation).GetOrderDetails(1);
```

This is only good assuming `DataService` does not derive from `IDisposable`.

Comment: Right, except I would then have to modify every class i wanted to add this behavior to.  I know I can do what you suggested, i was looking for a while to do this without boilerplate code.

Comment: "(I'll also mention that lowercased methods are against Microsoft guidelines for naming conventions, so I'll be using Pascal casing in my code.)"

who is microsoft and why do i care about their conventions? :D